# Is there a formula for converting a decimal value for number of minutes, to a duration-formatted value?

Tags: time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, duration

I have a cell that sums up a decimal count of minutes - for example "105", as in 105 minutes (decimal value).

All I wish to do is convert this decimal value to a duration-formatted value which includes hours, minutes, and seconds.

So the result I am looking for is a cell which has the following value:
"01:45:00" and is formatted as `HH:MM:SS`.

If the value "105" is in cell A1, is there a formula to "convert" this value into the "01:45:00" value, formatted as `HH:MM:SS`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:

```
=TEXT(A1/1440, "hh:mm:ss")
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>"", TEXT(A1:A/1440, "hh:mm:ss"), ))
```

[image: 0]

---

however **true duration** would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A<>"", TEXT(A1:A/1440, "[hh]:mm:ss"), ))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Nice. Can you elaborate on what you mean by "true duration"? I noticed the difference is the brackets around "hh".

Comment: sure, it means that if you have more minutes than 24hours the clock will not reset

Comment: Quick question: what's a good formula to use for displaying the 01:45:00 as "1h 45m 0s" ?

Comment: @ShianHan you can use TEXT - https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxY3K.png

Answer (score 1):

The `TIME( hour, minute, second )` function will work for this. The function allows values outside the usual `0-23` (h), `0-60` (m), `0-60` (s) range by recalculating other components accordingly, so `=TIME( 0, 120, 0 )` is equivalent to `=TIME( 2, 0, 0 )`.

In your case:

```
=TIME( 0, A1, 0 )
```

...then select the cell and choose a time formatting in `hh:mm:ss` format.

Note that the `TIME` function accepts only integer arguments:

> `TIME` will silently truncate decimal values input into the function, e.g. an hour of 12.75 will be interpreted as 12.

...so if you want to use fractional/non-integer hours, set the `second` parameter instead of the `minute` parameter, like so:

```
=TIME( 0, 0, A1 * 60 )
```

Comment: Just tried this. Seems to work except when A1 decimal value is 0.5 (which is half a minute). The formula =TIME(0,A1,0) returns "00:00:00" - but should return "00:00:30", right?

Comment: @ShianHan What happens if you use `=TIME( 0, 0, 60 * A1 )` ?

Comment: Yep, that seems to work now when A1 is between 0 and 1.